# Flutter & Firebase: How to validate if isNewUser Firebase and show WelcomeScreen Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm working on an app that has login, registration and home made with authentication via Firebase. And whenever the user creates the registration, he is going to the Home screen. I would like to check if the user is new to open the welcome screen after registration. How could I do that? Please specify in code how it would be done. Below is the auth.dart class where authentications are made with Firebase and landing_screen.dart where HomeScreen () is called. I would like to do the validation if the user is new to landing_screen.dart so that I can have the context when opening the Welcome screen after registration.
Thank you all for any help.

```
class LandingScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final auth = Provider.of<AuthBase>(context, listen: false);
​
    return StreamBuilder<User>(
        stream: auth.onAuthStateChanged,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
            User user = snapshot.data;
​
            if (user == null) {
              return SignInTypeScreen.create(context);
            }
​
            return HomeScreen();
          } else {
            return Scaffold(
                body: Center(
              child: Lottie.asset(
                'assets/circle-loading.json',
                height: 100.0,
                width: 100.0,
              ),
            ));
          }
        });
  }
}

And here Auth.dart where you can see the auth to signUp user

class User {
  User({@required this.uid});
  final String uid;
}
​
abstract class AuthBase {
  Stream<User> get onAuthStateChanged;
​
  Future<User> currentUser();
​
  Future<User> signInAnonymously();
​
  Future<User> signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password);
​
  Future<User> signUpUser(String email, String password);
​
  Future<User> signInWithGoogle();
​
  Future<User> signInWithFacebook();
​
  Future<void> signOut();
}
​
class Auth implements AuthBase {
  final _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
​
  User _userFromFirebase(FirebaseUser user) {
    if (user == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return User(uid: user.uid);
  }
​
  //do something when receive firebase User each time the user SignIn or Signout
  @override
  Stream<User> get onAuthStateChanged {
    return _firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged.map(_userFromFirebase);
  }
​
  @override
  Future<User> currentUser() async {
    final user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    return _userFromFirebase(user);
  }
​
  @override
  Future<User> signInAnonymously() async {
    final authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInAnonymously();
    return _userFromFirebase(authResult.user);
  }
​
  @override
  Future<User> signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    final authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);
    return _userFromFirebase(authResult.user);
  }
​
  @override
  Future<User> signUpUser(String email, String password) async {
    final authResult = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);
​
    if (authResult.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
      print('funciona');
    }
    return _userFromFirebase(authResult.user);
  }
​
  @override
  Future<User> signInWithGoogle() async {
    final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
    final googleAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    if (googleAccount != null) {
      final googleAuth = await googleAccount.authentication;
      if (googleAuth.accessToken != null && googleAuth.idToken != null) {
        final authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(
          GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
            idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
            accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
          ),
        );
        return _userFromFirebase(authResult.user);
      } else {
        throw PlatformException(
          code: 'ERROR_MISSING_GOOGLE_AUTH_TOKEN',
          message: 'Missing Google Auth Token',
        );
      }
    } else {
      throw PlatformException(
        code: 'ERROR_ABORTED_BY_USER',
        message: 'Sign in aborted by user',
      );
    }
  }
​
  @override
  Future<User> signInWithFacebook() async {
    final facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
    final result = await facebookLogin.logIn(
      ['public_profile'],
    );
    if (result.accessToken != null) {
      final authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(
        FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(
          accessToken: result.accessToken.token,
        ),
      );
      return _userFromFirebase(authResult.user);
    } else {
      throw PlatformException(
        code: 'ERROR_ABORTED_BY_USER',
        message: 'Sign in aborted by user',
      );
    }
  }
​
  @override
  Future<void> signOut() async {
    final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
    await googleSignIn.signOut();
    final facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
    await facebookLogin.logOut();
    await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }
}
```

Comment: There is many solutions to check if the user is new. With a FirebaseUser object you can check the date of creation of the user with user.metadata.creationTimestamp. Also, but it's more a way to check if the user has just install your app, you can set a boolean in the shared_preferences, if it's false, open the welcome screen, set the value to true, and then he will not see it again unless he reinstall the application.

Answer (score 0):

buildHome() {

```
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot) {
    print(snapshot?.data);
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return "home screen";
    }
    return "your welcome screen";
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this in my own project using shared_preferences.
I created a widget that opens an InformationScreen (WelcomeScreen for you) and then a TabScreen (HomeScreen for you) if it's the first time the user opens the application otherwise it goes straight to the TabScreen.

Here is the code, hope it helps!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import '../../screens/tab_screen.dart';
import '../../screens/information_screen.dart';
import '../../screens/splash_screen.dart';

/// Handles the transition from InformationScreen to TabScreen.
class SignInTransition extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignInTransitionState createState() => _SignInTransitionState();
}

class _SignInTransitionState extends State<SignInTransition> {
  Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  /// Checks if user has seen the information screen before.
  Future<bool> _getSeenInfoBefore() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
    return (prefs.getBool('seenInfoBefore') ?? false);
  }

  /// Saves that the user has seen the information screen before.
  Future<void> _setSeenInfoBefore() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
    await prefs.setBool('seenInfoBefore', true);
    setState(() {}); //* Rebuild the widget to transition to TabScreen.
  }

  /// Transitions to TabScreen.
  void handleTransition() {
    _setSeenInfoBefore();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<bool>(
      future: _getSeenInfoBefore(),
      builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          var seenInfoBefore = snapshot.data;
          return seenInfoBefore
              ? TabScreen()
              : InformationScreen(
                  onClose: handleTransition,
                );
        } else {
          return SplashScreen();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```